# why the variable URL is undefined?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a problem with a variable that take the value `undefined`.

In the file Create.cshtml i have:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Enrollment", FormMethod.Post, new
{
    id = "YearCourseFormId",
    data_courseListAction = @Url.Action("CourseList")
})) {
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)

<fieldset>
    <legend>Enrollment</legend>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.StudentId, "Student")
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.DropDownList("StudentId",  ViewBag.Student as SelectList, String.Empty, new { @class = "chosen-select", data_placeholder = "Please Select a Student...",style="width:350px;" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.StudentId)
    </div>


     <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Course.YearId, "Year")
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.DropDownList("YearId", ViewBag.Year as SelectList, String.Empty, new { @class = "chosen-select", data_placeholder = "Please Select a Year...",style="width:250px;" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Course.YearId)
    </div>


    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CourseId, "Course")
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.DropDownList("CourseId", String.Empty)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CourseId)
    </div>


    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Create" />
    </p>
</fieldset>
```

}

In the Jquery File i have:

```
$(function () {

$('#YearId').change(function () {
    var URL = $('#YearCourseFormId').data('courseListAction');
    alert(URL);
    $.getJSON(URL + '/' + $('#YearId').val(), function (data) {
        var selectList = $("#CourseId");
        selectList.empty();
        var option = $('<option>');
        selectList.append(option);
        $.each(data, function (index, optionData) {
            option = $('<option>').text(optionData.Text).val(optionData.Value);
            selectList.append(option);
        });

    });
});

});
```

In this part  `alert(URL);`the result is undefined.

In the EnrollmentController.cs i have:

```
    public ActionResult CourseList(string ID)
    {
        int Year = int.Parse(ID);
        var courses = from s in db.Courses
                          where s.YearId == Year
                          select s;

        if (HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest())
            return Json(new SelectList(
                            courses.ToArray(),
                            "Id",
                            "CourseName")
                       , JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

But this method is not called due to error.

What is the problem?

Comment: we would need to see the html of `#YearCourseFormId` i suspect you incorrectly created the dataAttribute as `data-courseListAction="somevalue"` rather than `data-course-list-action="somevalue"`

Comment: This code is seriously incomplete. What is `data_courseListAction`? What do you do with it? What does the rendered HTML sent to the browser look like?

Comment: @KevinB: Ah, yes, another victim of jQuery's unnecessary `data` magic... I'd forgotten that particular wrinkle.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: Ok, i going to add this method.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder In this case, isn't it that attributes are all lowercase, not jQuery's handling of it? `.data('courselistaction')` would work if he defined it in the way i suspect

Comment: @KevinB: No, it's jQuery. `attr` works just fine, for instance: http://jsbin.com/OyAs/2 No, the problem is that `data` takes `camelCase` and makes it `camel-case` (but yes, all lower case would also work). The whole interaction between the `data` function and `data-*` attributes is a design disaster. When accessing attributes, use `attr`. If you want to store arbitrary data on your elements with JavaScript, use `data`. Never expect the two to have any sensible interaction with each other, you'll be disappointed. :-)

Comment: @Esneyder we were more interested in seeing your HTML, not the courseList method which isn't being called anyway due to the error.

Comment: @KevinB: Ok, i going to add this.

Comment: Anyone familiar with asp know what `data_courseListAction = "ljkgha"` actually generates?

Comment: @Esneyder: Again: The ***rendered*** HTML. Not the ASP.Net code that renders it. When trying to diagnose a client-side problem, there's nothing like seeing what the client end of the connection is seeing.

Comment: It will generate the following <form id="YearCourseFormId" data_courseListAction="ljkgha" ...> So I believe that @KevinB is right

Comment: @LimoWanKenobi No, because .net anonymous object keys can't have a dash (`-`), you have to express the attribute with an underscore instead, and they are replaced with a dash in the html. Apparently, it also converts attribute names to lowercase as well, a behavior I was unaware of previously.

Comment: Good to know, thanks for research and confirming @JasonP

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: the first part of the rendered html is: <form action="/Enrollment/Create" data-courseListAction="/Enrollment/CourseList" id="YearCourseFormId" method="post"><input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden"  />    <fieldset>

Comment: Well that's interesting. What version of MVC are you using?

Comment: @JasonP: the version is MVC4

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your form is rendered like this:

```
<form action="/Enrollment/Create" data-courselistaction="..." id="YearCourseFormId" method="post">

</form>
```

You can access using any of these:

```
$('#YearCourseFormId').data('courselistaction');
$('#YearCourseFormId').attr('data-courselistaction');
$('#YearCourseFormId').attr('data-courseListAction');
```

Given T.J. Crowder's comments about quirks with `data()`, it would probably be safer to go with one of the `attr()` solutions.

Edit - The plot thickens..

Chrome inspecter:

[image: inspecter]

Source:

[image: source]

I'm not sure what the implications of that are, **but** my javascript snippet did work to get the value.

Comment: *"Your form is rendered like this"* Are you sure? Are you sure it's not rendered with `data-courseListAction="..."`? Because that [exhibits the same `data` behavior](http://jsbin.com/OyAs/2). (The solution works, I'm just asking the question about the assertion above it.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Yes, I just pasted the code into a project I'm working on. All my quick edits were to remove things related to my specific environment.

Comment: Interesting. According to the OP (in a comment -- *sigh*), it comes out as `data-courseListAction="/Enrollment/CourseList"` for him. But again, the solution works regardless, though I'd tend to prefer `attr('data-courseListAction')` barring a *really good reason* to use `data`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder See my edit. I'm not sure why that happens. I would tend to agree that `attr()` would be safer.